# why is this msgbox code popping an error?

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to make an msgbox with only an OK option, but needs to have description and a title.

```
MsgBox ("this is where i put my message", vbOKOnly, "this should be the title")
```

it just gives me an error message when i try to run the code

Comment: Where's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the parentheses

```
MsgBox "this is where i put my message", vbOKOnly, "this should be the title"
```

alternatively, you could do

```
rspns = MsgBox ("this is where i put my message", vbOKOnly, "this should be the title")
```

The latter would not be to your benefit though. If you were to use a messagebox from which you want to catch the response (e.g. `vbYesNo`) that would be a method to use, the response would be stored in the `rspns` variable.

Comment: that was exactly what i misunderstood, thanks a lot for the explanation
i had other working boxes but they were defining a var like the second code you put so i just thought it would always use parenthesis

Comment: It gets confusing at times